# Programa para de ler antes do for e "trava" durante o run (C)

Tags: c

Estou realizando este exercício em C que é um desafio para a faculdade. Não vale nota. O propósito é usar o *for* e achar pi. O enunciado está no corpo. Por algum motivo, quando eu dou *run* no programa, ele só para antes de ler o *for* e fica ali. Não dá erro fatal, nada. Ele só não continua. Rodei tanto no CodeBlocks quanto em um compilador online para conferir qual era o problema. Dei uma olhada no comando do for algumas vezes, mas não consegui identificar o problema.

**O código:**

```
*#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>*

int main (){

    int i, vezes, n_termos;
    float pi;
    float soma;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("Este programa utiliza a fórmula de Leibniz para calcular a constante pi:\n\n");

    printf("        1         1         1         1        1        1              pi \n");
    printf("       ---   -   ---   +   ---   -   ---   +  ---   -  ---  +  ... = -----\n");
    printf("        1         3         5         7        9        11             4   \n\n");

    printf("Para tal, insira um número de termos a serem considerados. O programa fica \n");
    printf("          mais preciso conforme mais termos são inseridos!                 \n");

    printf("\n\n///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n");

    printf("NÚMERO DE TERMOS = ");
    scanf("%d", &n_termos);

    soma = 1;
    vezes = 0;

    for (vezes; vezes = n_termos - 1; vezes + 1){

        if (vezes % 2 != 0){
        i = (3 * vezes) + 2;
        soma = soma - (1/i);}

        if (vezes % 2 == 0){ 
        i = (3 * vezes) + 2;
        soma = soma + (1/i);}
}

    pi = 4 * soma;

    printf("\nA constante pi é aproximadamente %f\n", pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que fazer? Obrigado!

Comment: `vezes = n_termos - 1` retorna `n_termos - 1`, que é verdadeiro a menos que `n_termos` seja igual a 1. Substitua por `vezes < n_termos`. E `vezes + 1`, substitua por `vezes++`.

Comment: @VanderSantos fiz a substituição, obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

No segundo argumento do `for` a variável `vezes` deveria ser expressada em:  `vezes<n_termos` ou `vezes <= n_termos-1`, pois esse é o critério de parada quando você incrementa o `vezes` no último parâmetro para que essa variável alcance a quantidade de termos do loop.

Comment: Beleza, vou corrigir isso!

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde..
Acho que só Consertar esta parte abaixo

```
vezes = n_termos - 1
```

dentro da primeira clausula do `for`, você tem o critério de inicialização (esta pode ser i=1 ou qualquer coisa ou até ficar vazia se já tiver inicializado sua variável)

dentro da segunda, é o critério de parada, este deve ter uma expressão booleana ou que retorne uma booleana

NO CASO ACIMA, VOCE USA UMA ESPRESSAO DE ATRIBUIÇÃO, A QUAL NAO RETORNA VALOR PARA A CLAUSULA, OU SEJA, ELA FICA SEMPRE FALSA TRAVANDO EM UM LOOP, EM ALGUNS CASOS NEM EXECUTA MESMO SEM MOSTRAR ERRO NA COMPILAÇÃO OU EXECUÇÃO,ISSO COSTUMA ACONTECER PRINCIPALMENTE EM LINGUAGEM C

É IMPORTANTE TER ATENÇÃO PARA USAR SOMENTE ( == , >= , <= , > , < OU  !=) PARA FAZER COMPARAÇÕES.

e no ultimo o critério de incremento, o qual roda ao final de cada execução, salvo a expressão `++(variável)` a qual incrementa a variável antes de executar o que esta dentro do `for`

Comment: Obrigada, vou conferir isso.